# looking for a round progress bar with up and down functionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, jquery-knob

I'm looking for a round progress bar for my site,

I need to progress bar to show a router output power when users are near and away from the router so I need a progress bar to be up and down functionally.

I find these two,but I'm having problem to implement them for my use,

http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

anybody know more good progress bar plugins?

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ - start at the source ;). If you're having implementation difficulties, you should post the specific problem you're having as a question.

Comment: jQuery UI is a great library and the progress bar is nice, but you do need [an extra plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-progressbarvertical/) to make the progress bar display vertically.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that the jQuery UI progressbar doesn't support vertical orientation by default.